# How to set local directory hosted on IIS as NuGet package source?

Tags: http, nuget, package, nuget-package

I've set up a local directory (C:\NuGet) to contain local NuGet packages. I then hosted this location on IIS (localhost:619). I then added this location in my NuGet.Config file like this:

```
<packageSources>
  <remove key="Local" />
  <add key="Local" value="http://localhost:619/" />
</packageSources>
```

When i open the package manager i get the following error:

`[Local] The V2 feed at 'http://localhost:619/Search()?$filter=IsAbsoluteLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework='net452'&includePrerelease=true&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.`

Is there a way to get around this error or make this work?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet only supports `.nupkg`s in a folder for filesystem based feeds (URLs that can be represented using file://). Any HTTP feed must implement one of the NuGet HTTP protocols. [The link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) billybob posted as a comment to your question lists several NuGet servers that you can host on your web server.

I'll point out Sleet, written by a former member of Microsoft's NuGet team. It's a static site generator, meaning it creates a bunch of files, and then you just serve those files the same way you're currently trying to serve the `.nupkg`s, it doesn't need a web app that dynamically generates content, or a database. But every time you add remove a `.nupkg`, you need to regenerate all the static files.

Alternatively, you could just use a network file share, rather than HTTP. Although it's inefficient if your developers use Visual Studio's Package Manager UI to search for packages, so you'd really be better off with any HTTP feed if you have a lot of `.nupkg`s.